# JQuery ajax post throws error

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax

When I try to send data to the server using Jquery POST I get the following error.

What am I doing wrong?

```
  $('.btnEditUser').click(function () {
          console.log('btn edit user clicked')
          var rowUser = $(this).parent()
          var rowUserData = rowUser.find(":input").val()
          var oForm = new FormData()
          oForm.append("rowUserData", rowUserData)
          console.log("oForm", oForm)
          var sUrl = 'edit-user/'
          console.log("sUrl ", sUrl);
          $.post(sUrl, oForm, function (uData) {
            console.log('SUCCESS')
          })
        })

**
```

Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
        at e (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js:4:7727)
        at Ab (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js:4:7608)
        at Function.r.param (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js:4:7918)
        at Function.ajax (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js:4:12227)
        at Function.r.(anonymous function) [as post] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js:4:14489)
        at HTMLButtonElement. (http://localhost:3000/view-users:62:9)
        at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js:3:10316)
        at HTMLButtonElement.q.handle (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js:3:8343)
    e @ jquery.min.js:4
    Ab @ jquery.min.js:4
    r.param @ jquery.min.js:4
    ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
    r.(anonymous function) @ jquery.min.js:4
    (anonymous) @ view-users:62
    dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
    q.handle @ jquery.min.js:3

**

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the value of **rowUserData**

```
var rowUserData = rowUser.find(":input").val()
```

It should not return HTML elements.